# How to replace html table with Perl Button

Tags: html, perl

Hello everyone i am new to Perl and scripting and i have this code:

```perl
print << "_END_HTML1_";
<div id="tabel">
<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th><input type=button value="Stop" onclick="document.getElementById('dostop').value='ON'; document.getElementById('formHiddenValues').submit();"/></th>
    <th><input type=submit value="Refresh" ></th> 
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<p><i>This window will be automatically refreshed after 10 seconds ...</i></p>
_END_HTML1_

system("cat /srv/www/htdocs/wwwrun-rw/$targetSystem-install_progress.txt 2>/dev/null");

print "</pre>\n";
if ( "$installfinish" eq "1" ) {
    $Params{'currentstep'} = 4;
    print "<p>Press Finish to acknowledge the operation result and reset the system state to IDLE.</p>";
    print "<input type=submit value='Finish' >\n";
 }
```

Can anyone show me how to replace that html table, all of it with that 'Finish' button?

Comment: Where do you populate $installfinish? Do you use plain CGI or something else?

Comment: I think you need to make yourself a lot clearer. Please show us an example of exactly the output you want to get.

Comment: Don't print the table if you don't know whether you want the table. Move the printing of the table into the `else` branch of the `if( $installfinish )` statement.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is more of a JS/HTML question. Here is my suggestion.

```
print <<EOF;
<script>
var replacement = "<p>This is a replacement</p>";
</script>
<input type=submit value='Finish' onClick='document.getElementById("tabel").innerHTML = replacement;'>

EOF
```

Comment: thank you but i need to replace it instant after the process is finished not when i click on finish